# Exchange contact pager number property missing?

Tags: outlook-addin

I'm trying to get the Pager Number from an Exchange contact. I'm getting the Exchange user from inside an Outlook addin and got access to the Global Address List.
The property should be available with this code, but the property tag doesn't exist it seems. I've found this ID many places, so I'm sure it's correct - or at least was... :)

.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3A21001F")

Found a long list of property tags here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb446002.aspx

When I'm using the tag for Pager/Beeper number 0x3A21001F the answer is that it doesn't exist.

If I use another like 0x3A06001F for Given name like this
propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3A06001F") there is no error, but it returns an empty string. So it seems that some properties exist and some don't

Comment: Do you see that property on the GAL object in OutlookSpy (click IAddrBook button and drill down to that entry)?

Comment: I used MFCMAPI and find that DASL, it just doesn't work. Installing OutlookSpy now to see if there is something I'm missing

Comment: And in OutlookSpy it's called PR_BEEPER_TELEPHONE_NUMBER_W and has the same DASL

Comment: Are you sure you are accessing the same GAL object in your code?